# How to add an interceptor to each request to keep ie from caching requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, axios

Internet explorer caches http requests. Instead of manually adding a header to each individual function I want to do something like this

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config): AxiosRequestConfig => {
return addNoCachingHeader(config);
  });
```

and

```
const addNoCachingHeader = (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
  return { ...config, headers: { ...config.headers, Pragma: "no-cache"} };
};
```

is there a simple way to keep IE from caching requests without going back through my whole app and adding headers to each individual request?

Comment: Why not send the right response headers?

Comment: @HMR sorry, I don't quite understand the question

Comment: If you don't want the response to be cached you should provide it with the right **response** headers. The client may not be the first consumer of the response, for example; in case of proxy. Therefore it should indicate in the response the appropriate caching for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a generic client approach would be better here.

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
  responseType: 'json',
  headers: { Pragma: "no-cache" },
});
```

And to use in other places import client and call `client.get` or `client.post`

if you want to override headers at some point, make this to a function

```
const client = (headers) => axios.create({
  baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
  responseType: 'json',
  headers,
});
```

and use as `client({ Pragma: 'no-cache' }).get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware with the header you want all your requests to use and then have your app use it with app.use(yourHeaderMiddleware(req, res, next)).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to add these 3 headers in every request:

```
{
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Expires': '0'
}
```

`Pragma` is deprecated but still required to [iOS Safari to work](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170714).

Just be sure to include these 3 headers in your backend CORS configuration. Otherwise you will find `Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` errors.

Sources:

- https://github.com/arthurfiorette/axios-cache-interceptor/issues/437#issuecomment-1361262194
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170714
- [Using JavaScript Axios/Fetch. Can you disable browser cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49263559/14681561)