# Vuejs axios get request always fetch new values

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

Hi to all i want to ask something about wordpress api!

I have one **button** in my vue when clicked fire a **function** who run an axios get request and fetch me the value of one field in specifiec post!

```
handleController(){
        axios.get('https://nice-ardinghelli.185-4-133-211.plesk.page/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams/'+this.team.id)
        .then(response => {
        this.isControllerSet = response.data.acf.acf_team_controller
        console.log(this.isControllerSet)
        })
    },
```

**Here is the wordpress backend**

[image: Backend wordpress]

**And here is the console.log result if i hit the button**

[image: Console.log]

The problem is:

1. When **wordpress** backend **user** update the value of the field the vue app don't fetch me the new value until i hit ctrl + f5. If i hard refresh i get the new value.
   How can i fetch always the new value when button clicked without hard refresh?

**Here is the wordpress user update the value**

[image]

**And here is the console.log result if i hit the button**

[image: Console.log]

2. When i POST data with axios and update this field it happens the same as above i don't get the fresh data until i hard refresh(CTRL + F5) my vue app

Comment: Do you mean that you're getting stale data from the `axios.get()` command?

Comment: If i don't hard refresh i can't get the updated value! I want always get updated value from wordpress backend! I get stale data until ctrl F5 but i cant ask the user to ctrl F5 to get updated data!

Comment: Check your network tab. Are you sure you’re getting updated payloads from your endpoint? Or is axios somehow caching them for you?

Comment: I cant explain that! If i hit the endpoint and change the value of the field in wordpress administrator panel i get updated value! If i get axios in the endpoint didnt get the updated value! I really can't figure out what happen? I want when user click the button to see if controller is set or no?

Comment: You didn’t answer my previous question. What does the network tab say? I’m not asking you to explain what happened. Just questions that’ll help with troubleshooting.

Comment: When i click the button and go to network i get 200 OK response but the data is not changed!

Comment: What is the response in the network? Does it show the updated value? Otherwise it's an issue with the WP backend and not client side (I have a feeling it is the former).

Comment: What i see is that the first time axios load the data but the other time i call axios to get data fetch it from disk cache! And of course without updated value

Comment: So that is your problem. Axios is caching your fetches.

Comment: Is there a way to Bypass this or always axios fetch data from disk cache!

Comment: See answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263559/using-javascript-axios-fetch-can-you-disable-browser-cache. This question is essentially a duplicate of that.