# Axios disable cache on the page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

So. I have two pages. On page **"A"** I use axios request to the server, I write GET parameters to `url` via `history.pushState(null, null, response.request.responseURL)`.

When I go to page **'B'** and press the **'back'** button, I see a json response instead of a page.

When I disable cache via devtools, then everything works fine.

How can I disable caching on page **"A"**?

p.s This behavior is only in Google Chrome.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you mean. Can you add the relevant code for when you say *"I write GET parameters to url via history.pushState"*

Comment: @AbirTaheer upd

Comment: You can find a few examples of how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263559/using-javascript-axios-fetch-can-you-disable-browser-cache)